# How to use wsdl2java created Java code?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl2java

I have a WSDL file using which I have generated server side classes in JAVA using ***axis2-eclipse-codegen-plugin-1.5.4*** and ***Axis 2 Service plugin***. The classes are created but I don't know how to use those classes and I cann't figure out which from all those classes is the main class. It has generated many other methods which I m unable to understand.

Now , I have to modify those classes for so that the service, when published, can send dummy data to client(I have to enter business logic). I am unable to do so. Can any body help/ any tutorials which can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start from this [Axis2 tutorials and articles](http://blogs.deepal.org/2009/06/axis2-tutorials-and-articles.html)

Answer (score 1):

If your setup will support it, starting with ejb3, writing basic beans and letting the server generate the wsdl on the fly might be easier. I've done this with glassfish3 and it worked really well.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial: [Developing Web Services Using Apache Axis2 Eclipse Plugins](http://wso2.org/library/1719). It is using an older version of the Axis2 Eclipse Plugin (1.3 when you are using 1.5.4), but hopefully the same steps apply, or you can figure them out based on the old tutorial.